# Back to previous screen in javafx with send value

Tags: javafx

I use javafx in intellij IDE.I think it may be Repetitious but I did not see solution. 
When I click to setchange Button on screen I want to close screen and back to previous screen but it open new screen 
and as you see save value to first textfield screen.I want a solotion with fxml GUI rather than javafx code. Thanks

Main.java:

```
public class Main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    Parent root = FMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample1.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 400));
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

Sample1Controller.java

```
public class Sample1Controller {
@FXML
private Button btn1;
@FXML
private TextField text1;

void initData(String s) {
    text1.setText(s);
}

@FXML
private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("sample2.fxml"));  
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    stage.setScene(new Scene((Parent) loader.load()));
    stage.show();
}
}
```

Sample2Controller.java

```
public class Sample2Controller {
@FXML
public Button btn2;
@FXML
public TextField text2;
@FXML
public Label lbl;
String string;
@FXML

private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    string = text2.getText();
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("sample1.fxml"));
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    stage.setScene(new Scene((Parent) loader.load()));
    Sample1Controller controller =
            loader.getController();
    controller.initData(string);
    stage.show();
}
}
```

sample1.fxml

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-   Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0"  xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.76-ea" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Sample1Controller">
    <children>
    <Button fx:id="btn1" layoutX="246.0" layoutY="135.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleButtonAction" text="go to scene 2 " />
    <Label layoutX="259.0" layoutY="229.0" text="this is scene 1" />
    <TextField fx:id="text1" layoutX="216.0" layoutY="285.0" />
</children>
</AnchorPane>
```

sample2.fxml

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" style="-fx-background-color: tan;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.76-ea" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Sample2Controller">
<children>
  <Button fx:id="btn2" layoutX="269.0" layoutY="200.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleButtonAction" text="SetChange" />
  <Label layoutX="269.0" layoutY="137.0" text="This is scene 2" />
  <TextField fx:id="text2" layoutX="226.0" layoutY="261.0" />
</children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: It's not clear what's wrong with the code you posted, or what you want it to do differently. Do you just want to use the same window each time?

Comment: I just want send data that entered in screen two be saved in screen one.

Comment: But your code already does that, it seems: `controller.initData(string)`.

Comment: however you click it open new window, maybe ten or farther,I need two window for this.First window open second window and second window gather information and send them to first window and then automatically close to see information at firsn window.

Comment: This is not complete program . I want know how it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Usual Approach

In `Sample1Controller` you can do

```
public class Sample1Controller {

    @FXML
    private Button btn1;
    @FXML
    private TextField text1;


    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("sample2.fxml"));  
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.initOwner(btn1.getScene().getWindow());
        stage.setScene(new Scene((Parent) loader.load()));

        // showAndWait will block execution until the window closes...
        stage.showAndWait();

        Sample2Controller controller = loader.getController();
        text1.setText(controller.getText());
    }

}
```

and in `Sample2Controller` do:

```
public class Sample2Controller {

    @FXML
    private Button btn2;
    @FXML
    private TextField text2;
    @FXML
    private Label lbl;

    private String text;

    public String getText() {
        return text ;
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        text = text2.getText();

        // close this window...
        btn2.getScene().getWindow().hide();
    }

}
```

---

### Without blocking

Blocking execution in the first controller (with `showAndWait()`) when you show the second window is usually what you want to do; however if you don't want to do that for some reason, you can use a listener to update when the window closes:

```
    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("sample2.fxml"));  
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.initOwner(btn1.getScene().getWindow());
        stage.setScene(new Scene((Parent) loader.load()));

        Sample2Controller controller = loader.getController();
        stage.setOnHidden(evt -> text1.setText(controller.getText()));

        stage.show();

    }
```

---

### Without closing the window

And finally, if you want to update the text at a time when the window isn't closed (but, say, a button is pressed), you can do:

```
    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("sample2.fxml"));  
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.initOwner(btn1.getScene().getWindow());
        stage.setScene(new Scene((Parent) loader.load()));

        Sample2Controller controller = loader.getController();
        controller.setTextCallback(text1::setText);

        stage.show();

    }
```

and then modify `SampleController2` as:

```
public class Sample2Controller {

    @FXML
    private Button btn2;
    @FXML
    private TextField text2;
    @FXML
    private Label lbl;

    private Consumer<String> textCallback ;

    public void setTextCallback(Consumer<String> textCallback) {
        this.textCallback = textCallback ;
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        if (textCallback != null) {
            textCallback.accept(text2);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: @hasan Please mark it as correct if it solves the problem

Comment: Thanks others too.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
@FXML
private AnchorPane container;

private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
Parent root;
    Stage stage;
    if (event.getSource() == btn2) {
        stage = (Stage) container.getScene().getWindow();
        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample1.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1650, 1000);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I am new programmer so what is the container?

Comment: Sorry, the container would be your pane. Basically give your pane an fx:id (i.e container)